# Spring is unable to perform cleanup of multipart items

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-boot

I am sending to controller multipartfile and when logic in controller is completed spring invokes error:

```
2015-09-10 10:41:05 WARN  (StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:91) - Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items
java.io.IOException: UT010015: Could not delete file ....\Path\undertow6870903013120486522upload
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.delete(PartImpl.java:111)
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/{name}/file", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="multipart/form-data")
 public ResponseEntity<?> receiveFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
@PathVariable("name") String name) throws IOException {
    logic here
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am using AngularJS (ng-file-upload module) to send file:

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
                            url: sUrl,
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {'Content-Type': '"multipart/form-data'},
                            file: file,
                            fileFormDataName: 'file'
                        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Tomcat or Undertow as your application server?

If it's Undertow, it may just be a benign exception informing you that the temporary file can't be deleted because it's already been deleted (source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3966 which also mentions a bug ticket open [UNDERTOW-542](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-542) ).

I ran into this same issue when running a jHipster-based project using the `fast` profile, which uses Undertow. Everything worked as expected, but this error was thrown. If I used the `dev` profile, which uses Tomcat, no error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I started using `Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE` with `wildfly 9.x`.

To fix the issue I just updated my Spring version from `4.2.2.RELEASE` to `4.2.3.RELEASE` which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is my service class

```
@Override
public String uploadImage(String path, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    // File Name
    String name = file.getOriginalFilename();

    //Random name generate of file
      String randomID=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      String fileName1= randomID.concat(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")));
    
    // Full Path
    String filePath = path + File.separator + fileName1;

    // Create folder if not create
    File f = new File(path);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
    }

    
    // file copy

    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), Paths.get(filePath));
    //System.gc();  //or 
    f.delete();
    /* I am resolve my exception using above System.gc(); or f.delete() method using both are working for me 
    */
    return fileName1;
}
```

Comment: file is open but not closed for this reason there is exception generated so use   System.gc();  or 
    f.delete();